# jquery ui autocomplete select function disaplay in fancybox

Tags: model-view-controller, fancybox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This is how i made it works.

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("SearchString")',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: request,
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data,
                            function(item) {
                                return { label: item.CustomerName, value: item.CustomerName, id: item.CustomerId };
                            }));
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $.fancybox.open({
                    src:'@Url.Action("Details")' + "/" + ui.item.id,
                });
            }            
    });
    });


</script>

<input id="search" />
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/fancybox-3.0/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/fancybox-3.0/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

> In the the "url" i am calling the SearchString method, returning label, value and id.
>   In the select event i open the selected item thrue a fancybox.